# How to plot a plane in 3D space using weights from gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient-descent

Is there a way to plot a plane in 3D space with 3 "weights" or slopes using `matplotlib`? I'm trying to visualize a linear regression plane from a gradient descent algorithm that returns 3 weights corresponding to 3 features.

I'm not sure how to convert this into something that a function like `Axes3D.plot_surface` can use?

Comment: I'm missing the statistics background to be certain, but as far as the plane is concerned, you should try to define a `z(x,y)` function which you can plot over a `meshgrid` using `Axes3D.plot_surface`. In general you need `z=m*x+n*y+c` where `m` and `n` are slopes with respect to `x` and `y`; odds are that your three weights are more like `m1*x+m2*y+m3*z=c`, in which case you should probably divide `m1,m2` by `m3`, and if `m3` is zero then you'd get infinite slope, in which case the plane is vertical, in which case `z(x,y)` won't work but `y(x,z)` might.